# Looking for simple way of communication between JavaScript and Java

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, websocket

**Intro:** I want to develop simple multiplayer Five in row (Gomoku). Front-end should be done using JavaScript, and back-end in Java.

Basically client and server should exchange pairs of integer numbers and game id. It's easy to do on client side with WebSockets, but...

**Question:** Is there *simple* way to process communication on server side, using Sockets and ServerSocket, without embedding Jetty or any other server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to do such thing on a web project, have a look at the [DWR project](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since Front-end is javascript it might run in a web browser. To communicate with the server most likely using http, then embedding Jetty and using dwr is the simplest way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[WebSockets browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support) is poor at the moment.

If you're creating a Web application the mainstream solution for JS-Java communication is Ajax with some JS framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/). It will not require any libs on the server side (unlike DWR) and also you don't need to put any JS stuff on your server if you use [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Comment: With the flash fallback this is hardly a problem: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Comment: Looking at the list of its [limitations](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js#readme) I would still prefer just plain Ajax...

Comment: It's university project. Did not think it is important to mention.