# Implementing Trade/Quote API(c++ or Java) with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, c++, html

I am doing a proof of concept for a HTML5 web app that will need to handle streaming data and sending and receiving financial trade information.  For this app I am initially targeting [**FXCM**'s ForexConnect API](http://www.fxcodebase.com/wiki/index.php/Category%3aForexConnect).  It is offered in c++, java, and .NET versions.

I am trying to find a way to avoid creating a server to sit between the client and the API( avoid incurring data costs).  Does any one have any suggestions or tricks that would allow me to implement this API from the client side javascript?

I would like the solution to be as cross-browser friendly as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Java can run on the client side, so that'd probably be your best approach. You could implement something in Java which makes data available to JavaScript, which could take it from there. You'd have to implement a small, possibly invisible Java applet. [Communicate between Java and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190239/looking-for-simple-way-of-communication-between-javascript-and-java)

I didn't see any listing for it, but if they had a web-based API you could do it that way as well (though looking at it's relative complexity, it probably doesn't).